# Regex: Matcher doesn't find a match

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

i have the following code

```
    String expression="a weird case of {asda}something";
    Pattern aPattern=Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
    Matcher matcher = aPattern.matcher(expression);
    boolean match = matcher.matches();
```

This wil always throw

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

I don't get why it will not find a match. The output should be {`asda}`. Any ideas?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/2

Comment: ... as you can see I say it doesn't work in java by using a mather.

Comment: Use `find()` instead. http://ideone.com/TjESYU

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception though. That must be your code doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Matcher#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) attempts to match the entire `String`. In your case, the regex you've provided does not match the entire expression. What you want is [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) and possibly [`group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group--) to get the result.

Comment: @diazazar If this answer solved you issue, please accept it. If you solved your issue yourself, please post and self-accept your own answer. This will mark this question as resolved. This is important for future visitors.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux you have to wait a while in order to accept an answer. :)